# How to clear error list of chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app

First introduction to chrome apps.  I'm trying to get some sort of workflow down.  I've enabled the checkbox to collect errors, but can not seem to clear them between executions of the app.  I assumed closing the app them re launching it would do the trick.  The only thing that works right now is deleting the app then reloading the package.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear the list of errors at "Collect errors":

1. Toggle the "Developer mode" checkbox (disable, then re-enable).
2. Click on the Reload link (reload extension/app).

Refreshing the page instead of reloading the app/extension also works.

Comment: See also [crbug.com/408347](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408347) for the feature request on getting an easy way to clear the error list.

Comment: But refreshing the page causes ALL extensions to reload.

Comment: @Xan Extensions are only reloaded if you press `Ctrl + R` or the reload button. Refreshing via F5, pressing Enter in the omnibox, or navigating forwards and back does not reload any extension, but it does reset the view.

Comment: False on the reload button/F5, to does reload everything. Only back/forward navigation doesn't.

Comment: @UziTech Still works for me in 38.0.2125.106 and 41.0.2221.0 on Linux.

Comment: chrome 40.0.2214.6 dev-m (64-bit) Windows 7. When I try this the errors are still there. The only thing I have found to work is removing and reloading the extension

Comment: @UziTech Chrome 40.0.2214.6 is close to 41.0.2221.0 in terms of features, so I think that you did not follow the steps from my answer, or the background page generates the error upon load (which will add an item to the list of collected errors). I've justed checked on Windows 7, beta and canary, and the answer works as expected.

Comment: The steps I took: 1. Uncheck "Developer mode" 2. Check "Developer mode" 3. Click "Reload (Ctrl + R)"; that is what your post says to do and the errors are still there.

Comment: @UziTech Do you see the old errors, or a list of new errors? Try Canary, perhaps you experienced a temporary bug that got fixed.

Comment: Works just fine in 41.0.2220.0 canary (64-bit)

Comment: @UziTech Great. Unfortunately you cannot retract the downvote unless the answer is edited, but I'm glad that it helped ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 39.0.2171.95 64-bit Chromium all I need to do is toggle the `Developer mode`

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution suggested by Rob does not work anymore for recent versions of Chrome.

You clear the errors by following the steps below.

1. Go to [chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions)
2. If it's not enabled, enable the Developer mode, see below.
   [image]
3. Click on the `Errors` button (in red in the picture below) on the extension.
   [image]
4. Now you can either delete each single error by clicking on the trashbin icon next to it, or you can just clear all errors by clicking on the `Clear all` button depicted below.
   [image]