# Is the collect errors a feature for ChromeOS release channel?

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I'm working on collecting logs for my application. I didn't see it in ChromeOS 64 release channel. But I saw there is a "collect errors" button at the bottom of applications in chrome://extensions on ChromeOS 65 dev channel. What it stranger is that according to [How to clear error list of chrome app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048416/how-to-clear-error-list-of-chrome-app) this seems existed 3 years before.

So I'd like to know if the collect errors feature is released or will be released in future?

Thanks,
Allisa

Comment: I think as seen in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048416/how-to-clear-error-list-of-chrome-app), yes it is already existing. However, there is still a feature request logged ([1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=482526) and [2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408347)) for an easy way to clear the error list. You may also check this [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=368819).